# Performance optimizations of information retrieval in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, prolog, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I wanted to do some information retrieval tasks with Prolog. Currently I have a (large) set of distinct Prolog theories representing the dependencies in a sentence (incidentally, I store these Prolog codes in a text file) - and I want to find only those theories which are matching for a user defined goal clause.

For example I have Prolog codes like this:

```
rel("nsubjpass","seen","It",S):-S is 1.
rel("aux","seen","can",S):-S is 1.
rel("auxpass","seen","be",S):-S is 1.
...
rel("prep", X, Y, S):-rel("dobj", Z, X, SCORE1), rel("prep", Z, Y, SCORE2), S is SCORE1*SCORE2.
...
rel(_,_,_, S):-S is 0.0001.
```

And I want to search for goal clauses like this:

```
?- rel("nsubj", WRONG, "Russell", SCORE1), 
   rel("nsubj", WRONG, "Russell", SCORE2), 
   ... , 
   rel("dobj",DOING,SOMETHING, SCORE9).
```

If I do a simple `foreach`-like loop over the theories, the search time will be getting slow as the number of the theories increases, so I have to introduce some optimalizations.

My idea is that to create an inverted index, where I could maintain the frequency of every term, and the ID of the theories where they are occured. Then when it comes to search, I would first filter out the unnecessary theories which otherwise wouldn't contained in the results.

Are there any other well-tried methods or good patterns and algorithms on the field of information retrieval that can handle this problem well?

Comment: Did you use double quoted strings on purpose ?

Comment: This data comes from a parser. The first component of the tuple is an identifier of the dependency (I could use there atoms, this would increase the performance, nice point) - but the other components can contain apostrophes, and other "stringy" stuff, so these wouldn't be valid atoms.

Comment: writeq (or specifier ~q in format) takes care of details regarding atom representations.

Comment: performance could really be *much* better with atoms because of first argument indexing (I guess - help page is not simple)

Comment: Hmm thanks for the tip! :) I will try it out. Maybe reordering the parameters would help a bit? Oh, I want to mention that I use TuProlog, which I run from Java code. I don't know whether it's a super fully-featured Prolog engine, or not...But I will check it in the docs.

Comment: I guess your choice of implementation should depend on the specificity of your task. In other words, what are your exact reasons for choosing TuProlog, and does it fit your needs? If you represent your data as facts in the Prolog database, make sure they are indexed, as this will make fact lookup very efficient. On the other hand, any algorithm that does not depend on memory addressing (static arrays) can be usually implemented efficiently enough in Prolog.

Comment: I chose TuProlog because searching in the database is only a part of the software (which is written is Java). I have to use parsers and a lot of string-manipulation stuff which would be inconvenient to do in Prolog. What do you mean on that the Prolog database is indexed? Do you mean the inverted-index which I did mention in the post?

Comment: Parsing is _very_ convenient in Prolog, this is what it was initially designed for. Look at DCGs. I don't know for other implementations, but SWI-Prolog has built-in predicates for atoms that make "string" (in atom form) manipulation very easy. About indexing (in SWI): fact lookup is **not** just a sequential search http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,'2.17',swi('/doc/Manual/jitindex.html'))

Comment: and also http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(3,'4.13.2',swi('/doc/Manual/db.html'))

Comment: On parsing I mean dependency parsing and NLP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Boris's answer is reasonable from a Prolog developer point of view, but I didn't want to spend too much time to investigate how could I call Java functions from Prolog and vice versa, not to mention the problem of creating a standalone executable from the Prolog scripts which is a requirement for me.

So I was a bit stubborn and I tried to implement my original idea of creating an inverted index from the Prolog terms and it works flawlessly. So now when I want to search for a certain Prolog goal, in the first step I can filter the "database" for the relevant theories: I compute the intersection of the occurences of the terms, and I run the Prolog engine with only these theories.
Another big performance optimization was to share a singleton TuProlog engine between the individual searches, and it also decreased the memory overhead.
Oh and I also refactored the rules too, for example now I write this:

```
rel(nsubjpass, "seen","It", 1).
```

instead of this:

```
rel("nsubjpass","seen","It",S):-S is 1.
```

I didn't notice any big performance boost from this change, but at least it didn't get slower :)

With these changes, now it can be seen that the real bottleneck of the performance is not running the Prolog engine, but using NLP libraries...but it's another issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am writing this as an answer instead of a comment just because comments are very limiting.

First of all, if you indeed plan to use Prolog, it would pay off to do some research on

1. The language itself:

   - what are its strengths and weaknesses?
   - can I achieve my goals in idiomatic Prolog (have similar problems been solved already)
2. Different implementations:

   - what does a particular implementation offer over others
   - how easy it is to interface an implementation with other languages

After a short struggle in the beginning, I have been using SWI-Prolog exclusively, so I am biased. But SWI offers a very complete, general, reasonably efficient implementation, excellent documentation, and is completely open-source.

Moving on, you seem to be using Prolog facts to represent your data. Prolog facts in the form:

```
foo(a,b,1).
foo(a,d,10).
...
```

build the *Prolog database*. Most implementation offer some sort of indexing of facts, so that a query like "give me 'foo's with 'a' as the first argument":

```
?- foo(a,B,X).
B = b, X = 3;
B = d, X = 10.
```

does a very efficient search through all available facts and returns the ones matching your query. You definitely don't need to search through facts with a for loop, or code a fact search algorithm. Note, however, that fact indexing can vary between implementations.

Furthermore, depending on your use-cases, representing strings as Prolog atoms could be the best solution, efficient and easy-to-implement. Look [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.21%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipatom.html%27%29%29), especially towards the end, for some very useful "string manipulation" predicates on atoms.

Moving on, writing top-down, left-to-right parser in Prolog is a feature of the language, using DCGs (definite clause grammars).

At the end, if you are comfortable with Java and need only to add an efficient (dynamic) data store, Java + SQL might be the better choice.